# How to sync firebase database while receiving push notification in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have created a chat application which is working fine, but while receiving notification i wants to sync firebase database so that data will be in offline mode also.

i have tried using sync mode but this didn't worked

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("somepath");
databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
```

but this is not working while receiving notification.

In simple lines, i wants to sync the firebase database persistence state in background service(FirebaseMessagingService).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your expectation is with the code you're showing.  Could you edit the question to be more specific about what isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson proper now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your service is a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), and showing a notification, Android will kill the app process, and synchronization will stop.  So, you will have to arrange for your service to be a foreground service, or accept that synchronization will not happen when the user isn't actively using the app.